# How to check whether a comment is flagged on a page using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have worked a lot on facebook graph api and used fql also. Recently i got a task to get all comments which are flagged on a specific page.
Could someone can help me out to get the solution. I searched a lot but unable to find the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately information about whether a comment is flagged is not accessible through any of facebook APIs

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=86342